# Есть ли возможность изменить шрифт и размер определённой строки в QPlainTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

Я хочу изменить свойства определённого текста (шрифт / размер) в общем виджете QPlainTextEdit.(QtCreator)
например первая строка была с шрифтом 'Serif' а вторая - System.

Comment: Проще всего использовать HTML и вставить теги: <font ...> </ font>. 
Мне так кажется.

Comment: вы имеете в виду метод setStyleSheet() ?

Comment: К си вопрос не имеет отношения, т к. Фреймворк предназначен для с++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще то QPlainTextEdit (исходя из его названия) не предназначен для сложного форматирования текста. Но он содержит функцию [appendHtml](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#appendHtml). Попробуйте ее. Может будет достаточно.

Если же нет, переходите на [qtextedit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html) - он как раз для этого всего и предназначен.